# Detected new usb device connected/disconnected on Qt

Tags: windows, qt, events, notifications, usb

I want to be notified when a new usb device is connected or disconnected (device hid). I have succeeded to be notified when there is a usb device change but I don't know if the device is connected or disconnected. 
The message I receive (when usb attached or detached) is the same : 
message : 537 (VM_DEVICECHANGE)
wParam : 7
lParam : 0

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QAbstractEventDispatcher>
#include <QAbstractNativeEventFilter>
#include <QDebug>
#include <windows.h>
#include <dbt.h>
#include <QObject>

class MyNativeEventFilter : public QAbstractNativeEventFilter {
public :
    virtual bool nativeEventFilter( const QByteArray &eventType, void *message, long *result )
    Q_DECL_OVERRIDE
    {
        if (eventType == "windows_generic_MSG")
        {
          MSG *msg = static_cast<MSG *>(message);
          static int i = 0;

              msg = (MSG*)message;
                  qDebug() << "message: " << msg->message << " wParam: " << msg->wParam
                      << " lParam: " << msg->lParam;
              if (msg->message == WM_DEVICECHANGE)
              {
                  qDebug() << "WM_DEVICECHANGE";
              }
            }
        return false;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    MyNativeEventFilter myEventfilter;
    app.eventDispatcher()->installNativeEventFilter(&myEventfilter);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Offtopic: why do you need a custom window? Just use `qApp->eventDispatcher()->installNativeEventFilter( yourEventFilter);`. `yourEventFilter` should be a child of `QAbstractNativeEventFilter`

Comment: @DmitrySazonov Thanks for the trick but I have always the same "problem" (I have edited my post)

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I use in one of my projects to get notified for USB connections/deconnections:

```
/** deviceeventfilter.h **/
class DeviceEventFilter: public QObject, public QAbstractNativeEventFilter
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit DeviceEventFilter(QObject *parent = 0);
    virtual bool nativeEventFilter(const QByteArray &eventType, void *message, long *result);

signals:
    void newUSBDevice();
    void lostUSBDevice();

public slots:
    void registerEvent(QWindow *window);
};

/** deviceeventfilter.cpp **/
DeviceEventFilter::DeviceEventFilter(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{

}

bool DeviceEventFilter::nativeEventFilter(const QByteArray &eventType, void *message, long *result)
{
    Q_UNUSED(eventType);
    Q_UNUSED(result);
#ifdef Q_OS_WIN32
    MSG *msg = (MSG *)message;
    if( WM_DEVICECHANGE == msg->message && DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL == msg->wParam )
    {
        qDebug("USB arrival detected!");
        emit newUSBDevice();
    }
    else if( WM_DEVICECHANGE == msg->message && DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE == msg->wParam )
    {
        qDebug("USB departure detected!");
        emit lostUSBDevice();
    }
#endif
    // Return false so that the event is propagated
    return false;
}


void DeviceEventFilter::registerEvent(QWindow *window)
{
    if( window != nullptr )
    {
#ifdef Q_OS_WIN32
        GUID guid = ...;

        DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE NotificationFilter;

        ZeroMemory( &NotificationFilter, sizeof(NotificationFilter) );
        NotificationFilter.dbcc_size = sizeof(DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE);
        NotificationFilter.dbcc_devicetype = DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE;
        NotificationFilter.dbcc_classguid = guid;
        HDEVNOTIFY hDevNotify = RegisterDeviceNotification((HANDLE)window->winId(), &NotificationFilter, DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE);
        if( NULL == hDevNotify )
        {
            // Print error
        }
#endif
    }

}

/** main.cpp **/
int main()
{
    ...
    DeviceEventFilter event_filter;
    QWindow *w = qApp->allWindows().first();
    event_filter.registerEvent(w);
    app.installNativeEventFilter(&event_filter);
    ...
}
```

Comment: msg->wParam is equal to DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL or DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE only if I plug (or unplug) usb key. If I plug mouse for example it doesn't work

Comment: It seem that receiving only `DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED` is a common problem.
You might find the following interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28998625/c-win32-not-receiving-dbt-devicearrival-or-dbt-deviceremovecomplete-on-wm-devi

Answer (score 0):

The [WM_DEVICECHANGE message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363480) doesn't really tell you whether a device was connected or disconnected.  After receiving that message, your application should use SetupAPI to look at all the USB devices that are connected and take an appropriate action.

Comment: When you get a `WM_DEVICECHANGE` message you can check `wParam` against `DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL` or `DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE`.

Comment: But the OP is getting DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED so both of those checks would fail.

Comment: wParam is equal to 7 ( DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED.). If i understand it's not possible to know easily if it's a connection or a remove. I use an API to see hid device (hidapi), I think the best is to use it to know if it's a connection or remove